# InDesign: how to get table correctly aligned on master page

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, tables, formatting

Working on a magazine in InDesign that is 204mm wide x 279mm high.

I have a header which reads: *TEL: 555 123 456 YOUR FREE WEEKLY MAGAZINE 18th - 24th November 2016* (edited since in screenshot) as a three-column table, set in Helvetica LT 8pt font inside a 179mm width text box.

What I am trying to do is get the header to fit exactly as 1cm left and 1cm right.

The other document I created has the same dimensions and same header but different phone number: 204mm wide x 279mm high with a header in a 179mm text box but I am trying to get it to fit as 0.9cm left, 1cm right [left page], 0.5cm left, 1.3cm right [right page].

[image: Magazine picture from InDesign CC]

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're struggling with, could you maybe add some screenshots?

Comment: Screenshots would be good, as this is not very clear. Are we talking about two completely different documents, or left and right-side pages in the same? Are you using only A-masters?

Comment: I've added a screenshot, and this is for B-Master - inner pages with advertising header. They are two separate documents but same page size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a 3x1 table as a holder for your header? How about splitting your header into 3 text boxes instead, align them how you'd wish. I'd take a guess at left-, center- and right-aligned, going from left to right respectively. Then adjust your 3 text boxes widths as preferred, using vertical guides if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are asking about 2 documents. My response here refers to the first issue:

- Your page is 204mm wide.
- Subtract 20mm for left + right page margins. You now have 184mm, which is **exactly** what your table width should be.
- Each cell width can then be [adjusted independently](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-tables.html), you just need to make sure they add up to exactly 184mm. Try 52+52+80 and ajust these until it looks right.
- After adjusting your cell widths, make sure the text box which contains the table is also 184mm wide and move its `X` location to 10mm.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, I know.....

---

I would not use a *table* at all.

Just a single text frame...

- Text aligned left
- 1 center tab (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- 1 right-aligned tab (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

The **right-aligned tab** forces all text *after* the tab to align right in the text frame. This is how it's possible to have both left aligned and right aligned text in the same frame.

So..... [ phone ] <kbd>Tab</kbd> [ weekly magazine ] <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> [ date ]

Then set the center tab <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

I don't really understand why a *table* is necessary.